# How to externalize and load property file from external path in a spark job when submitting the job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, typesafe, typesafe-config

I am using java8 and spark 2.4.1 to write my spark-job, in which I am using TypeSafe to load the property file i.e. application.properties which is located in "resources" folder, whose contents are like below

```
dev.deploymentMaster=local[8]
dev.spark.eventLog.enabled=true
dev.spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false
dev.spark.executor.memory=8g
```

In program I am loading the same as below passing "environment" variable as "dev" while submitting the spark job i.e. spark-submit

```
 public static Config loadEnvProperties(String environment) {
      Config appConf = ConfigFactory.load();
      return  appConf.getConfig(environment);
  }
```

Above is working fine....but this "application.properties" file is inside the "resources" folder.

How can I pass the "application.properties" file path while submitting from spark-submit job ? What changes I need to do in my code using TypeSafe? can you please provide some sample if possible in java?

In sprint boot we have something called profiling like application-dev.properties , application-qa.properties and application-prod.properties etc.... to load those specific environment properties is there something like possible in spark while submitting the job? If so can you please provide some details or snippet how to do achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

> but this "application.properties" file is inside the "resources"
>   folder.
>
> How can I pass the "application.properties" file path while submitting
>   from spark-submit job ?

1) prepare maven assembly or shade plugin/sbt distribution structure as `bin` for `shell` scripts `lib` for libraries or uber jar conf for all configuration files like application.properties or application.conf

example distribution structure :

```
.
└── yourproject
    ├── bin // all shell scripts and spark-submits
    ├── conf // your property file environment wise
    │   ├── application.conf
    │   └── log4j.properties
    └── lib   // your jars or uber jar
```

2) prepare a shell script which will accept the envt parameter use like below

> Deploy-mode cluster :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --num-executors 4 --driver-memory 6g --executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 4 --files conf/application_$env.conf --class yourclass lib/yourjar.jar
```

> Deploy-mode client :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 4 --driver-memory 6g --executor-memory 20g --executor-cores 4 --files conf/application$env.conf --spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Dconfig.file=conf/application$env.conf  --spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Dconfig.file=conf/application$env.conf --class yourclass  lib/yourjar.jar
```

your configfactor.load will load from this `-Dconfig.file=conf/application$env.conf`
but in deploy-mode cluster it may not load from this system property since your driver is not local machine. its one of the node in your cluster.

`-- files` will pass your file to  temp directory under your hdfs.
 `--files` you can just refer to the file name without any path
you may need to use `ConfigFactory.parseFile(configFile)` instead of `ConfigFactory.load()` in cluster mode. since I observed that `load` loading `\etc\spark\conf\spark-default.conf` as I observed in my case.

Comment: just try this first next step you will understand automatically. in cluster mode  `Config appConf = ConfigFactory.load();` may not work. you need to pass actual application.conf file  ... `ConfigFactory.parseFile(configFile)` since driver will be one of the nodes in the cluster not your local machine

Comment: if you are okay please care to [accept answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: thank you , Ram here the property file is still inside the jar right ie conf/application$env.conf??  can i point it to ./somefolder/application$env.conf ??

Comment: yes thats what I was saying dont put property file inside the jar  see maven assembly plugin to integrate your distribution

Comment: Ram  I tried as you suggested but it is not working .. I guess I  am missing something... plz check here once  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330285/unable-to-pass-dconfig-file-option-in-spark-submit-job-how-to-fix-it

Comment: copy the properties file in hdfs and try to access programatically