# How to access external property file in spark-submit job?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 2.4.1 version and java8.
I am trying to load external property file while submitting my spark job using spark-submit.

As I am using below TypeSafe to load my property file.

```
 <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
```

In my code I am using

```
public static Config loadEnvProperties(String environment) {
      Config appConf = ConfigFactory.load();  // loads my "resouces" folder "application.properties" file
      return  appConf.getConfig(environment);
  }
```

To externalize this "application.properties" file I tried this as suggested by an expert while spark-submit as below

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name Extractor  \
--jars "/local/apps/jars/*.jar" \
--files /local/apps/log4j.properties \
--files /local/apps/applicationNew.properties \
--class Driver \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=./applicationNew.properties \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=./applicationNew.properties \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=. \
  migration-0.0.1.jar sit
```

I placed "log4j.properties" & "applicationNew.properties" files same folder where I am running my spark-submit.

**1)** In the above shell script if I keep

```
--files /local/apps/log4j.properties,  /local/apps/applicationNew.properties \
```

**Error :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/local/apps//applicationNew.properties
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
```

So what is wrong here ?

**2)** Then i changed above script like shown i.e.

```
  --files /local/apps/log4j.properties \
    --files /local/apps/applicationNew.properties \
```

when I run spark job then I will get following error.

```
19/08/02 14:19:09 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: User class threw exception: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'sit'
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
```

So what is wrong here ? why not loading the applicationNew.properties file ?

**3)** When I debugged it as below 
i.e. printed "config.file"

```
String ss = System.getProperty("config.file");
logger.error ("config.file : {}" , ss);
```

**Error :**

```
19/08/02 14:19:09 ERROR Driver: config.file : null
19/08/02 14:19:09 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'sit'
```

So how to set "config.file" option from spark-submit ?

How to fix above errors and load properties from external applicationNew.properties file ?

Comment: try this, `--driver-java-options -Dconfig.file=./path/conf.file`

Comment: @Lamanus which version of spark are you using ? mine is 2.4.1 ... nope same error 19/08/02 16:40:12 ERROR Driver: config.file : null
19/08/02 16:40:12 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'sit'

Comment: 2.4.x worked but mine has only one config file. --files did not work in my case.

Comment: @Lamanus I can remove other --file to check if it works , what about executor java options?

Comment: I didnt and never seen that kind of option yet.

Comment: @Lamanus I kept only one file , still no luck ... Driver: config.file : null
19/08/02 19:03:20 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'sit'
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'sit'

Comment: @Lamanus what option  you are referring ?

Answer (score 2):

### --files and SparkFiles.get

With `--files` you should access the resource using `SparkFiles.get` as follows:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --files README.md

scala> import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark._

scala> SparkFiles.get("README.md")
res0: String = /private/var/folders/0w/kb0d3rqn4zb9fcc91pxhgn8w0000gn/T/spark-f0b16df1-fba6-4462-b956-fc14ee6c675a/userFiles-eef6d900-cd79-4364-a4a2-dd177b4841d2/README.md
```

In other words, Spark will distribute the `--files` to executors, but the only way to know the path of the files is to use `SparkFiles` utility.

### getResourceAsStream(resourceFile) and InputStream

The other option would be to package all resource files into a jar file and bundle it together with the other jar files (either as a single uber-jar or simply as part of CLASSPATH of the Spark app) and use the [following trick](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

```
this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceFile)
```

With that, regardless of the jar file the `resourceFile` is in, as long as it's on the CLASSPATH, it should be available to the application.

I'm pretty sure any decent framework or library that uses resource files for configuration, e.g. Typesafe Config, accepts `InputStream` as the way to read resource files.

---

You could also include the `--files` as part of a jar file that is part of the CLASSPATH of the executors, but that'd be obviously less flexible (as every time you'd like to submit your Spark app with a different file, you'd have to recreate the jar).

Comment: thank you , but everytime I put the files in jar , how it would be externalizing the property files ?

Comment: Every file of the Spark app is distributed by `spark-submit` automatically (that's one of the features of Spark) so you don't have to worry about it. The question is then how to access the files (inside or outside jar files) in a code that expect it on a file system in a given location. That's what `SparkFiles.get` does.

Comment: I don't think that `SparkFiles.get` is the only way. From what I see when running jobs on various environments, if a file is distributed via the `--files` option, it is available in the current working directory of the job being run, so a relative path would work correctly.

Comment: @Shyam _"everytime I put the files in jar , how it would be externalizing the property files ?"_ It's only now when I understood your question. Spark does not re-package your jar files. They are available as is, but your question was how to access the resource files and one way is to use `SparkFiles.get` or...see my updated answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to list files for the `--files`, `--jars` and other similar arguments is via a comma **without any spaces** (this is a crucial thing, and you see the exception about invalid main class precisely because of this):

```
--files /local/apps/log4j.properties,/local/apps/applicationNew.properties
```

If file names themselves have spaces in it, you should use quotes to escape these spaces:

```
--files "/some/path with/spaces.properties,/another path with/spaces.properties"
```

Another issue is that you specify the same property twice:

```
...
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=./applicationNew.properties \
...
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties \
...
```

There is no way for spark-submit to know how to merge these values, therefore only one of them is used. This is the reason why you see `null` for the `config.file` system property: it's just the second `--conf` argument takes priority and overrides the `extraJavaOptions` property with a single path to the log4j config file. Thus, the correct way is to specify all these values as one property:

```
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties -Dconfig.file=./applicationNew.properties"
```

Note that because of quotes, the entire `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="..."` is one command line argument rather than several, which is very important for spark-submit to pass these arguments to the driver/executor JVM correctly.

(I also changed the `log4j.properties` file to use a proper URI instead of a file. I recall that without this path being a URI it might not work, but you can try either way and check for sure.)

Comment: any advice how to do this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479581/how-to-do-this-scenario-in-spark-streaming?noredirect=1#comment101437596_57479581

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski any advice how to do this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479581/how-to-do-this-scenario-in-spark-streaming?noredirect=1#comment101437596_57479581

Comment: can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename